# angularjs switch between directive templateurl and $http service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having following directive

```
app.directive('myPage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: app.urlBuilder('about')
    }
})
```

This directive will be loaded by default

To switch the tab I have loaded multiple pages as a tab content for this I have used $http service in angular.

This is my html

```
<my-page></my-page>
<div>{{datas}}</div>
```

My controller

```
app.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$http', 'PageService', function($scope, $http, PageService) {
    $scope.changePanel = function(url) {

        PageService.getPageTemplate(url).success(function(data) {
            $scope.datas = data;
        })

    }
}])
```

The problem is initially  is loaded with about.html and changePanel is click event while click event occurs new page will be loaded and created $scope and used in template as `{{datas}}`. **Once datas is loaded now can i remove `<my-page></my-page>` content.**

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-if`:

```
<my-page ng-if="!datas"></my-page>
```